# Speed up touch.locationInNode(self) as it takes to long

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, instruments

Why it takes so long to take first element from the set (line: 120)? Is here a way to do it quicker?
As well method locationInNode (line: 121) takes ages. I would like to get some suggestions how would be possible to speed up it?

[image: TimeProfiler output]

moveDestroyLine function called a lot of time. Whenever user moves finger on the screen. 9 ms spend on this method in 3 seconds timeframe. What I noticed as well when CPU gets busy (60%) then I starting to notice sluggish UI responses.

Comment: 120: dont know. 121: because you do some calculation. How long does it take in actual time, this is just relative, which does not really get you anywhere... What would you like to happen? Would it be "better" if line 122 would take up 20% and 121 only 26,9%?

Comment: I added comment under the image.